# Sequelize - alias attributes with prefixed table name

Tags: sequelize.js

I have a Sequelize query that includes two seperate tables that I want to pull a field from each of those tables.  I also want to alias the attributes to give them better names.

This works.  It gives me the last two fields as `name` and `value`.

```js
const files = await db.Sheet.findAll({
        raw: true,
        attributes: [
            'sheet_name',
            'sheet_file_name',
            'updated_at',
            'active',
            'Chemical.name',
            'Load.value'
        ],
```

Now this does not work:

```js
const files = await db.Sheet.findAll({
        raw: true,
        attributes: [
            'sheet_name',
            'sheet_file_name',
            'updated_at',
            'active',
            ['Chemical.name', 'chemical'],
            ['Load.value', 'load']
        ],
```

I get the error: `original: SQLError: (conn=5809, no: 1054, SQLState: 42S22) Unknown column 'Chemical.name' in 'field list'`.  I thought that was the right way to alias an attribute.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Ended up finding the answer right after I posted the question.  Instead of deleting it, maybe it might help someone in the future.

```js
const files = await db.Sheet.findAll({
        raw: true,
        attributes: [
            'sheet_name',
            'sheet_file_name',
            'updated_at',
            'active',
            [Sequelize.col('Chemical.name'), 'chemical'],
            [Sequelize.col('Load.value'), 'load']
        ],
```